# How to remove a specific tag from the entire html page using jsoup

Tags: java, html, dom, tags, jsoup

i'm using jsoup 1.7.3 to edit some html files.

what i need is to remove the following tags from the html file :

```
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
<meta name="CREATED" content="0;0">
<meta name="CHANGED" content="0;0">
```

As you see its the  tag, how can i do that, here what i've tried so far :

```
//im pretty sure that the <meta> tag is nested in the <header>
but removing the whole  header is bad practice.

Document docsoup = Jsoup.parse(htmlin);
docsoup.head().remove();
```

what do you suggest ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend you use [Jsoup selectors](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html), for example

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements selector = document.select("meta[name=GENERATOR]");

for (Element element : selector) {
    element.remove();
}

doc.html(); // returns String html with elements removed
```

Comment: This can be done in 1 line:
Jsoup.parse(html).select("script,hidden,style,form").remove().html()